# this, current context-when should I use in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, keyword

I am not very sure with the use of "this" [current context] in jquery.What I know is- it prevents the dom from searching all the elements, it just work on that current element, which improve performance[correct me if I am wrong].Also I am not sure when  to use this and when not.
lets say, should I go for

```
  $("span",this).slice(5).css("display", "none")
```

or

```
 $("span").slice(5).css("display", "none")
```

both will work, but I am not very clear as how really it works.can somebody explain it with a diff/proper example, and when to use what?
[EDIT]

```
      $(function() {
        $("#clickme").click(function() {
            $("span",this).slice(5).css('display', 'block');//doesn't work ? why?
             $("span").slice(5).css('display', 'block');//works..why?

        });
    });
enter code here <span id="clickme">Click me</span>
                 <span>itam1</sapn>
                <span>itam2</sapn>
                <span>itam3</sapn>
                 <span>itam4</sapn>
                    <span>itam5</sapn>
                    ...upto10
```

Comment: You will need to provide your HTML for us to help you with this. Your first line would work if all the `spans` were contained within the `#clickme` element.

Comment: ok, its outside the #clickme element.so should I go for find()..will it improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can use the `this` keyword on event handlers since it will be a reference to the element that triggered the event and other jQuery functions like `$.each`.

For example when handling a click event lets say:

```
$('.parentElement').click(function () {
  $('.foo', this).hide();
});
```

The above code, will hide all the elements with class `foo` that are descendants of the currently `parentElement` that was clicked.

The use of the context argument of the jQuery function is the equivalent of making a call to the `find` method:

```
$(expr, context);
// is just equivalent to:
$(content).find(expr);
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your example:

```
    $("#clickme").click(function() {
      $("span",this);//... (1)
      $("span");//..       (2)
    });
```

The first line, will look for all the `span` elements that are **inside** of `#clickme` (its *descendants*), since that element was the one that triggered the `click` event.

The second line, will look for **all** the `span` elements on the whole page.

Comment: Ha ha. I think all my examples made my explanation less clear than yours. Great answer. Concise and very clear.

Comment: then for the 2nd line should i go for  find()? I dont want to apply my code to all the spans...it should be for some specific span....I have updated the html

Answer (score 0):

**How it works**

Lets use this HTML for the examples:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="column"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
   <div class="column"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <a href="#">Link 3</a><a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

The scoping parameter of the jQuery function should only be used if you already have a cached reference to a DOM element or jQuery wrapped element set:

```
var $set = $('#container');
$('a', $set).hide(); // Hides all 'a' tag descendants of #container
```

Or in an event:

```
$("#container").click(function(e){
   $('a', this).hide(); // Same as call above
}
```

But it makes no sense to use it like this:

```
$('a', '#container').hide()
```

When it should be written like this:

```
$('#container a').hide();
```

Having said all that, it is generally cleaner and clearer to just use `.find()` instead of using the second parameter in the jQuery function if you already have the jQuery or DOM element. The first example I gave would be written this way instead:

```
var $set = $('#container');
$set.find('a').hide(); // Hides all 'a' tag descendants of #container
```

If this one call was the only reason you grabbed the `#container` object, you could also write it this way since it will still scope the search to the `#container` element:

```
$("#container a").hide(); // This is the same as $('a', "#container");
```

**Why would you scope your selections**

When jQuery looks for an unscoped selector, it will search through the entire document. Depending on the complexity of the selector, this could require *a lot* of searching. If you know that the element you are looking for only occurs within a specific parent, it will really speed up your code to scope the selection to that parent.

Regardless of what method of scoping you choose, you should always scope your selectors whenever possible.